# BubbleWrap HTTP get request

Tags: http-get, rubymotion

I have an app that I am trying to pull data from a remote database. I have the url and the table columns and database name but i'm not sure how to call on that database with an http get. Below is my code:

```
def self.data
  BubbleWrap::HTTP.get("url", {credentials: {username: '***', password: '***'}}) do |response|
     p response.to_s

  end
end
```

I know this request is working because it shows me data in the console.I can't find anywhere how to request information from a database attached that url. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been working with Ruby for a year now but new to RubyMotion.

Comment: It's the job of whatever is listening at the other end of that url to marshal the data and respond to your request. How is the database 'attached' to that url? Sounds like you need to either: talk to whoever is maintaining that web service, or write that web service yourself -- a Rails implementation would make that pretty trivial, lots of examples out on the net.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand exactly your question, but you might want to take a look at this [link](http://rubymotion-tutorial.com/9-http/) and this [one](http://rubymotion-tutorial.com/10-api-driven-example/), explaining how to retrieve and handle data from a service.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This may be too elementary, but with an HTTP request you are not querying a database, you are requesting data from an HTTP server. It's the job of the server to look your request over, go to the database, retrieve the data, package it (often in JSON format), and ship it back. I believe that's what @railsdog was referring to in terms of marshaling.

Now, a couple of other comments:

1. `"url"` in your code should be an actual endpoint like `https://my.server.org/api/some_endpoint.json`. The payload containing credentials can be attached as a query string, however, you might want to consider POST and SSL, as I say in my next point.
2. You should never send credentials in clear text over HTTP. If you have to send sensitive information, use HTTPS (set up your server to respond to SSL-encrypted requests).
3. It's probably best to authenticate once on first request and get a token you can use on subsequent requests so as not to expose usernames and passwords unduly. Perhaps you can fill in a few blanks about what your server is (Rails, some public API, other) and it will make it easier to help.
4. You will need to accept the data from the server in some recognizable format. JSON is very well supported. BubbleWrap has a JSON parser to help turn the results into a hash. Alternate formats are XML (ick) or XML-RPC (ick, ick), or SOAP (ick, ick, ice).

If you're way ahead of me on this and it's too basic to be of use, I apologize.